# Django : How to upload CSV file in unit test case using APIClient from rest_framework

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

```
def test_upload_csv_success(self):
    """Test uploading a csv file"""
    
    with open("innovators.csv", "w") as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow(["SN", "Name", "Contribution"])
        writer.writerow([1, "Linus Torvalds", "Linux Kernel"])
        writer.writerow([2, "Tim Berners-Lee", "World Wide Web"])
        writer.writerow([3, "Guido van Rossum", "Python Programming"])                       
        
    with open("innovators.csv", "r") as file:              
        res = self.client.post(
            CSV_URL, {"file": file}, content_type="multipart/form-data"
        )        
    file.close()

    

    self.assertEqual(res.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    #self.assertIn('file', res.data)
    #self.assertTrue(os.path.exists(self.csv_model.file.path))
```

Below is the error, I/m getting

## System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
.F.

### FAIL: test_upload_csv_success (core.tests.test_csv_api.CsvUploadTests)
Test uploading a csv file

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/rounaktadvi/django_rest_api_projects/csv-store-api/core/tests/test_csv_api.py", line 56, in test_upload_csv_success
self.assertEqual(res.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
AssertionError: 400 != 201

Comment: files are send over the wire generally in binary mode i.e. in the form of bytes. When opening the file for reading, you should open it in binary mode.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it, out here's what i did

```
@patch("pandas.read_csv")
@patch("pandas.DataFrame.to_sql")
def test_upload_csv_success(self, mock_read_csv, mock_to_sql) -> None:
    """Test uploading a csv file"""
    file_name = "test.csv"
    # Open file in write mode (Arrange)
    with open(file_name, "w") as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        # Add some rows in csv file
        writer.writerow(["name", "area", "country_code2", "country_code3"])
        writer.writerow(
            ["Albania", 28748, "AL", "ALB"],
        )
        writer.writerow(
            ["Algeria", 2381741, "DZ", "DZA"],
        )
        writer.writerow(
            ["Andorra", 468, "AD", "AND"],
        )
    # open file in read mode
    data = open(file_name, "rb")
    # Create a simple uploaded file
    data = SimpleUploadedFile(
        content=data.read(), name=data.name, content_type="multipart/form-data"
    )

    # Perform put request (Act)
    res = self.client.put(CSV_URL, {"file_name": data}, format="multipart")
    # Mock read_csv() and to_sql() functions provided by pandas module
    mock_read_csv.return_value = True
    mock_to_sql.return_value = True

    # Assert
    self.assertEqual(res.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    self.assertEqual(res.data, "Data set uploaded")
    # Delete the test csv file
    os.remove(file_name)
```